# How to detect DataFormWebPart list name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dataformwebpart

i m learning sharepoint and i have a project which has lots of codes.

now i want to determine a list which is the source of a DataFormWebPart. but i do not know how to do it.

i m sharing the codes below

```
<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" Description="" ImportErrorMessage="Bu Web B&#246;l&#252;m&#252; alınamıyor." PartOrder="0" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="True" Title="Tablo4" ViewFlag="8" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" AllowConnect="True" FrameState="Normal" PartImageLarge="" AsyncRefresh="False" ExportMode="All" Dir="Default" DetailLink="" ShowWithSampleData="true" ListId="df76ae41-38ce-47d2-b71c-00c35cef2b1a" ListName="{DF76AE41-38CE-47D2-B71C-00C35CEF2B1A}" FrameType="None" PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" ManualRefresh="False" ChromeType="None" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" ViewContentTypeId="" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" MissingAssembly="Bu Web B&#246;l&#252;m&#252; alınamıyor." HelpMode="Modeless" ID="g_51527b71_a960_4999_8c5c_655ad7d5cba0" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True" IsIncludedFilter="" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{51527B71-A960-4999-8C5C-655AD7D5CBA0}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
<ParameterBindings>
<ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="ManualRefresh" Location="WPProperty[ManualRefresh]"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="ListID" Location="None" DefaultValue="{DF76AE41-38CE-47D2-B71C-00C35CEF2B1A}"/> 
<ParameterBinding Name="yil" Location="QueryString(yil)" DefaultValue=""/>
</ParameterBindings>
<DataFields>

@Title,Başlık;@FileLeafRef,Ad (formlarda kullanmak için);@FSObjType,Öğe Türü;@ContentType,İçerik Türü;@Created_x0020_Date,Oluşturma Tarihi;@FileRef,URL Yolu;@File_x0020_Type,Dosya Türü;@ContentTypeId,İçerik Türü Kimliği;@ID,Kimlik;@FolderChildCount,Alt Klasör Sayısı;@_UIVersionString,Sürüm;@Author,Oluşturan;@Y_x0131_l,Yıl;@_x00d6_zkaynak,Özkaynak;@Bakanl_x0131_k,Bakanlık;@D_x0131__x015f_,Dış;@_x00d6_zkaynak0,Özkaynak0;@Bakanl_x0131_k0,Bakanlık0;@D_x0131__x015f_0,Dış0;@_x00d6_zkaynak1,Özkaynak1;@Bakanl_x0131_k1,Bakanlık1;@D_x0131__x015f_1,Dış1;@_x00d6_zkaynak2,Özkaynak2;@Bakanl_x0131_k2,Bakanlık2;@D_x0131__x015f_2,Dış2;@TGBId,TGBId;@_x00d6_zkaynak3,Özkaynak3;@Bakanl_x0131_k3,Bakanlık3;@D_x0131__x015f_3,Dış3;@Harcama_x0020_T_x00fc_r_x00fc_,Harcama Türü;@Harcama_x0020_T_x00fc_r_x00fc__x,Harcama Türü:No;@Harcama_x0020_T_x00fc_r_x00fc__x0,Harcama Türü:IsChild;@Bakanl_x0131_kT,BakanlıkT;@_x00d6_zkaynakT,ÖzkaynakT;@D_x0131__x015f_T,DışT;@Harcama_x0020_T_x00fc_r_x00fc__x1,Harcama Türü:Kimlik;@TGBId_x003a_TGB,TGBId:TGB;@TGBId_x003a_Kimlik,TGBId:Kimlik;@yil_,yil_;@Harcama_x0020_T_x00fc_r_x00fc__x2,Harcama Türü:Destek_;@Harcama_x0020_T_x00fc_r_x00fc__x3,Harcama Türü:parent_;@IDO,IDO;@Modified,Değiştirme;@Created,Oluşturma Tarihi;@Editor,Değiştiren;@Attachments,Ekler;@FileDirRef,Yol;@_HasCopyDestinations,Kopyalama Hedefleri Var;@_CopySource,Kopyalama Kaynağı;@_ModerationStatus,Onay Durumu;@_UIVersion,Kullanıcı Arabirimi Sürümü;@ItemChildCount,Öğe Alt Öğe Sayısı;</DataFields>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Consider the following Parameter.

   ```
   <ParameterBinding Name="ListID" Location="None" DefaultValue="{DF76AE41-38CE-47D2-B71C-00C35CEF2B1A}"/>
   ```
2. Append this list ID {DF76AE41-38CE-47D2-B71C-00C35CEF2B1A} to your web address.

So it will look something like this:

```
http://servername/WebName/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List={DF76AE41-38CE-47D2-B71C-00C35CEF2B1A}
```

Open the URL thus created and you will be redirected to the respective list's settings page where you'll find the name of the list. Enjoy!